# Is there a way to determine if scrollbars are visible on a TDBGrid

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin, tdbgrid

I want to display something in the bottom right of a `TDBGrid`, but I don't want to overwrite the scrollbars.

Is there a nice way of determining if the scrollbars are visible? (and their size)

Comment: You could simply use the `ClientRect` property which is the rect not occupied by scroll bars. Compare with the `BoundsRect` property.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Perfect, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the best approach is to use the [`ClientRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ClientRect) property, which gives the client rectangle of the control in its own coordinates (which implies that `Left` and `Top` are always `0`). The "client rectangle" is the part of the control which is not border and scroll bar.

For comparison, the [`BoundsRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.BoundsRect) property is the full rectangle of the window in the parent window's coordinate system.

For example,

[image: Screenshot of a control with a scrollbar, and its BoundsRect and ClientRect values.]

and

```pascal
pnSnowman.SetBounds(
  DBGrid1.Left + DBGrid1.ClientWidth - pnSnowman.Width - 8,
  DBGrid1.Top + DBGrid1.ClientHeight - pnSnowman.Height - 8,
  pnSnowman.Width,
  pnSnowman.Height
);
```

results in

[image: Control with snowman in its bottom-right corner.]

Comment: Thanks, a nice explanation as well as code example.